# Azure app service mismatch in node js version that I set for linux but works for windows

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created both Linux and Windows app services. On both of them I set the node version to 18 but when I go to the debug console on (https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole) and check the node version I get v14.19.2 on Linux but version 18 on Windows.

I have also set the app setting WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION to ~18 but no luck.

[image]

Comment: I'm getting a blank screen when I try https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host

At the bottom left side of the page, it says waiting for connection and then connection closes soon after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I have created both Linux and Windows Azure App Service to check the same in my environment.***

**Linux Web App:**

[image]

To check the Node version of Linux App Service, open the `NEW UI of its KUDU site` with URL `https://<App_Name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui`:

[image]

***As an alternative, you can check the Linux web app's node version by using the command:***

```
 az webapp config show --name <Web_app-Name> --resource-group <Resource_Group_Name>| jq '.linuxFxVersion'
```

[image]

- To set the Node Version of web app, use the command:

```
az webapp config set --resource-group <Resource_Group_Name> --name <Web_App_Name> --linux-fx-version "NODE|18-lts"
```

[image]

**Windows Web App:**

[image]

[image]